# Word Add-in for working with files over WebDAV

Tags: ms-word, add-in, webdav

I want to make a ms word add-in, that does this:

It asks for a user, password and a network path which correspond to a WebDAV server, for a certain user, and if entered correctly, displays an interface from which a user can select to create, or open a file. When a user opens a document, he can click save, and that file will get updated on the server.

I'm asking if this is doable and if yes, what tools should I use and how should I approach the problem?

Comment: Using Windows' built-in WebDAV functionality instead is not an option? I think Vista / 7 allow mapping WebDAV resources to a drive

Comment: @Pekka Yeah - with SharePoint at least, this works OOTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to roll your own - rather than using the Windows OR Office offerings - you might take a look at http://wiki.exoplatform.com/xwiki/bin/view/JCR/Microsoft+Office+plugin